# time series rolling function per group

Tags: r, grouping, rolling-computation

I have a dataset of the following type:

```
      ID     date       RET
1  10026 20171227 -0.003768
2  10026 20171228  0.008958
3  10027 20171227 -0.001447
4  10027 20171228 -0.017454
5  10028 20171227 -0.009988
6  10028 20171228  0.013813
```

I need to calculate the rolling sd of RET with a window of 252 for every ID. For that, the function

```
roll_sd(df50[,2],252)
```

Does the job of calculating the rolling sd but does not account for different ID. I know I could write a loop of the type

```
for (i in 1:dim(list_of_all_ID_to_be_created)) {
  roll_sd(df50[i,2],252)
}
```

and then attach this values to an empty dataframe. However, is there a way o do it all at once such that in my original dataframe I just get a new column "roll_sd" which does the calculation for each ID? Desired result would look like:

```
      ID     date       RET  roll_sd
1  10026 20171227 -0.003768  0.18667
2  10026 20171228  0.008958  0.21667
3  10027 20171227 -0.001447  0.18668
4  10027 20171228 -0.017454  0.32542
5  10028 20171227 -0.009988  0.87763
6  10028 20171228  0.013813  0.11221
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `roll_sd` with a window size of 252 will make the first 252 values in each group `NA` - it won't give the result you suggest in your question. However, of the several ways you could achieve the result, the easiest is probably to use `group_by` and `mutate` from the tidyverse family of packages. I have dropped the resultant`NA` values from the final data frame using `drop_na`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(roll)

df <- data.frame(ID = rep(letters[1:5], 500), RET = rnorm(2500))

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(roll_sd = roll_sd(RET, 252)) %>% 
  drop_na(roll_sd)
#> # A tibble: 1,245 x 3
#> # Groups:   ID [5]
#>    ID       RET roll_sd
#>    <fct>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 a     -0.538   1.02 
#>  2 b     -0.669   1.08 
#>  3 c     -0.438   0.990
#>  4 d     -0.511   1.06 
#>  5 e      0.953   1.04 
#>  6 a     -1.68    1.02 
#>  7 b     -0.806   1.08 
#>  8 c     -1.86    0.995
#>  9 d      3.49    1.08 
#> 10 e     -1.36    1.05 
#> # ... with 1,235 more rows
```

Comment: it works wonderfully! About the NaN it is not a problem, it is normal that it works that way. In my "real" dataframe I took one year more of data to be able to have a complete time series of rolling sd calculated in this way.

Comment: @Matteo I'm glad about the NA issue - I was wondering whether I'd misunderstood the question!